# How to run js file in mongo using spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In mongo shell js file can be run using `load` command:

```
load("path/to/file/file.js")
```

How to do this using spring-data? Or any other way in Java.
I've tried:

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.append( "$load" , "/path/file.js" );
CommandResult t=mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);
```

and:

```
obj.append( "$eval" , "load(\"/path/file.js\")" );
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: The MongoDB shell is a JavaScript REPL so it essentially runs a JavaScript engine  ( v8 actually ). if you wanted to load and run JavaScript in your Java application then you similarly would need to embed a JavaScript engine. But seeming that your JavaScript is likely just shell commands then this should be of little use to you. What you should be doing is rewriting the code, and whatever purpose you think that file serves is probably better handled anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the relevant section of the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.server-side-scripts) on how to work with scripts in Spring Data MongoDB.

```
ScriptOperations scriptOps = template.scriptOps();

// Execute script directly
ExecutableMongoScript echoScript = new ExecutableMongoScript("function(x) { return x; }");
scriptOps.execute(echoScript, "directly execute script");     

// Register script and call it later
scriptOps.register(new NamedMongoScript("echo", echoScript)); 
scriptOps.call("echo", "execute script via name");
```

Comment: This doe not work for me.
code ...
scriptOps.register ...
fails for me (exactly same code used)
Error:
--------
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.script.NamedMongoScript] to type [com.mongodb.DBObject]

--------

Comment: Make sure you use Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 or better. It has added support for those operations (see [these](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/a0e42f5dfecf92b386a5d3d6e05b5b2d4f5dce64) [commits](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/39d931200551750b718566a5de596d7628774114)) for details.

Comment: @OliverGierke can we Executable script is long will it execute ?? in my case its not executing

Comment: This is throwing 'Error: "not authorized on test to execute command' for me. How can we give authentication details in the script?

Comment: This does not work for mongoDB 4.2 and superior. So it is deprecated by spring. It seems Mongo removed the "eval" command which was used by Spring. cf
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ScriptOperations.html

Answer (score 4):

What if you read text of your JavaScript from the file manually and put it into $eval? Something like:

```
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            new File("/path/file.js")));
    try {
        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            text.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } finally {
        try { br.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
    obj.append("$eval", text.toString());
    System.out.println(mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj));
```

If it works then check that your file is accessible in server-side file system. Because load() is executed on server side.

Comment: "$eval" was removed by the mongo team as of mongo version 4.2.