# How to run mongodb shell command with Spring data mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

When I'm running an aggregation file into mongo , I use the mongo utility 
like:

```
mongo localhost:27017/mydb aggregationfile.js
```

How I can do the same programmatically with Spring Data `MongoTemplate`?

Comment: mongoTemplate.aggregate() is this what you are looking for?

Comment: seems like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486488/how-to-run-js-file-in-mongo-using-spring-data should answer your question.