# Run js file in mongo using spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to run js file using mongo-template. 
[See StackOverFlow thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486488/how-to-run-js-file-in-mongo-using-spring-data)

I am trying to use same code base, no change at all. 
This does not work for me.
I get Exception at this line:

```
scriptOps.register(new NamedMongoScript("echo", echoScript));
```

### Error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.script.NamedMongoScript] to
>   type [com.mongodb.DBObject]

Complete StackTrace ...

> org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:375)
>     at

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
         StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\piyush\\t.js")));
        try {
            while (true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                text.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            try { br.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {

                System.out.println(ignore);
            }
        }

        ExecutableMongoScript echoScript = new ExecutableMongoScript(text.toString());
        Object ob=mongoOperation.scriptOps().execute(echoScript, "hello"); 
        System.out.println(ob);
```

---

t.js

```
function(x)    { return x; }
```

it will print `hello`