# Spring MongoDb template for shell commands

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-shell, spring-mongodb

I am trying to create an application where I can pass the shell commands for mongoDB and then execute it in java.

One of the exmaple I tried is as below

```
 DBObject dbobject=(DBObject) JSON.parse("{$and:[{sections.data.rowIdx: {$in: [1]}},{year:2015},{issuerId:19038},{sections.data.values.numValue:3548}]}");
```

This example works with Native java code. NOw I want to use Spring boot and springframework using mongodbtemplate. Is there a way to execute such shell commands directly?

Or should I look for another Springfamework solution?

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486488/how-to-run-js-file-in-mongo-using-spring-data

Comment: I think it doesnt clearly tell. If i need to do execute a query like    db.getCollection('InsStatData').find({$and:[{'sections.data.rowIdx': {$in: [1]}},
{year:2015},{issuerId:19038}]})